# NodeJS: app failsafe mechanism approach?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I'm building a NodeJS app which will be the core of a robot. What I want to do is to make a failsafe-like mechanism, which will catch any of the app errors/crashes (in case they appear) and, for example, stop the robot and gently restart the app.
I've searched for such a solution, but with no luck. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Perhaps pm2 is suitable for this

Comment: Also, you can "try" and "catch" over your whole code and any errors would then cause an caught exception instead of a kill?